# GraphDB clear automatically duplicate triples?

Tags: duplicates, repository, graphdb, triples, named-graphs

I have a question about how graphDB work with multiples graphs in the same repository: If 2 different graphs has the same triples, the graphDB keep the 2 triples (duplicated) or clean?

Answer (score 2):

It will keep both of them, depend on the query it will display what you need.
Lets do the following example, first we will add the statements in first graph:

[first graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHdow.png)

Then add the same triple in new graph in same repo:

[second graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYxTl.png)

If you then query both of them, both will display the statements

[filtered result on first graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXkcQ.png)

[filtered result on second graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIcHR.png)

Comment: and is there any way for graphDB to automatically clean up duplicate triples from different named graphs?